# Why is size_of::<MyStruct>() not equal to the sum of the sizes of its fields?

Tags: struct, rust, memory-alignment, memory-layout

I tried to measure the size of a struct and its fields ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e0f5e963715939302755d5b92632f587&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::mem;

struct MyStruct {
    foo: u8,
    bar: char,
}

println!("MyStruct: {}", mem::size_of::<MyStruct>());

let obj = MyStruct { foo: 0, bar: '0' };
println!("obj:      {}", mem::size_of_val(&obj));
println!("obj.foo:  {}", mem::size_of_val(&obj.foo));
println!("obj.bar:  {}", mem::size_of_val(&obj.bar));
```

This program prints:

```
MyStruct: 8
obj:      8
obj.foo:  1
obj.bar:  4
```

So the size of the struct is bigger than the sum of its field's sizes (which would be `5`). Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is due to [*padding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) in order to satisfy a types [*alignment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) requirements. Values of specific types  don't want to live at arbitrary addresses, but only at **addresses divisible by the types' *alignment***. For example, take `char`: it has an alignment of `4` so it only wants to live at addresses divisible by 4, like `0x4`, `0x8` or `0x7ffd463761bc`, and not at addresses like `0x6` or `0x7ffd463761bd`.

The alignment of a type is platform dependent, but it's usually true that types of size `1`, `2` or `4` have an alignment of `1`, `2` and `4` respectively, too. An alignment of `1` means that a value of that type feels comfortable at any address (since any address is divisible by `1`).

So what about your struct now? In Rust,

> composite structures will have an alignment equal to the maximum of their fields' alignment.

This means that the alignment of your `MyStruct` type is also `4`. We can check that with [`mem::align_of()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.align_of.html) and [`mem::align_of_val()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.align_of_val.html):

```
// prints "4"
println!("{}", mem::align_of::<MyStruct>());
```

Now suppose a value of your struct lives at `0x4` (which satisfies the struct's direct alignment requirements):

```
0x4:   [obj.foo]
0x5:   [obj.bar's first byte]
0x6:   [obj.bar's second byte]
0x7:   [obj.bar's third byte]
0x8:   [obj.bar's fourth byte]
```

**Oops**, `obj.bar` now lives at `0x5`, although its alignment is 4! That's bad!

To fix this, the Rust compiler inserts so called *padding* -- unused bytes -- into the struct. In memory it now looks like this:

```
0x4:   [obj.foo]
0x5:   padding (unused)
0x6:   padding (unused)
0x7:   padding (unused)
0x8:   [obj.bar's first byte]
0x9:   [obj.bar's second byte]
0xA:   [obj.bar's third byte]
0xB:   [obj.bar's fourth byte]
```

For this reason, the size of `MyStruct` is 8, because the compiler added 3 padding bytes. Now everything is fine again!

... except maybe the wasted space? Indeed, this is unfortunate. A solution would be to swap the struct's fields. Fortunately for this purpose, the memory layout of a struct in Rust is unspecified, unlike in C or C++. In particular, the Rust compiler is allowed to change the order of fields. You cannot assume that `obj.foo` has a lower address than `obj.bar`!

And since **Rust 1.18**, this optimization is performed by the compiler.

---

But even with a Rust compiler newer or equal to 1.18, your struct is still 8 bytes in size. Why?

There is another rule for memory layout: a struct's size must always be a multiple of its alignment. This is useful to be able to densely layout those structs in an array. Suppose the compiler will reorder our struct fields and the memory layout looks like this:

```
0x4:   [obj.bar's first byte]
0x5:   [obj.bar's second byte]
0x6:   [obj.bar's third byte]
0x7:   [obj.bar's fourth byte]
0x8:   [obj.foo]
```

Looks like 5 bytes, right? Nope! Imagine having an array `[MyStruct]`. In an array all elements are next to each other in the memory:

```
0x4:   [[0].bar's first byte]
0x5:   [[0].bar's second byte]
0x6:   [[0].bar's third byte]
0x7:   [[0].bar's fourth byte]
0x8:   [[0].foo]
0x9:   [[1].bar's first byte]
0xA:   [[1].bar's second byte]
0xB:   [[1].bar's third byte]
0xC:   [[1].bar's fourth byte]
0xD:   [[1].foo]
0xE:   ...
```

Oops, now the array's second element's `bar` starts at `0x9`! So in fact, the arrays size needs to be a multiple of its alignment. Thus, our memory looks like this:

```
0x4:   [[0].bar's first byte]
0x5:   [[0].bar's second byte]
0x6:   [[0].bar's third byte]
0x7:   [[0].bar's fourth byte]
0x8:   [[0].foo]
0x9:   [[0]'s padding byte]
0xA:   [[0]'s padding byte]
0xB:   [[0]'s padding byte]
0xC:   [[1].bar's first byte]
0xD:   [[1].bar's second byte]
0xE:   [[1].bar's third byte]
0xF:   [[1].bar's fourth byte]
0x10:  [[1].foo]
0x11:  [[1]'s padding byte]
0x12:  [[1]'s padding byte]
0x13:  [[1]'s padding byte]
0x14:  ...
```

---

*Related*:

- [Chapter about memory layout in the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html)
- [Similar question on the C++ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Possibly worth noting that while memory layout optimization has always been theoretically possible, it wasn't actually implemented until this year (thanks to [some really awesome work by Austin Hicks](http://camlorn.net/posts/April%202017/rust-struct-field-reordering.html)).

Comment: Also worth noting that the size of a struct will always be a multiple of its alignment, so that sequentially laid out elements of an array stay aligned. So even if you put the char first and the u8 second, you'd still have padding. Rearranging elements is interesting if you have multiple u8s in the struct; the compiler can group them together.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the default `#[repr(Rust)]` layout, there are other options available, [as explained in the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html).

You can make your representation more tightly packed, using `#[repr(packed)]`:

```
#[repr(packed)]
struct MyStruct {
    foo: u8,
    bar: char,
}
```

This will align all the fields to the nearest byte, regardless of their preferred alignment. So the output would be:

```
MyStruct: 5
obj:      5
obj.foo:  1
obj.bar:  4
```

This may be less performant than the default Rust representation and many CPUs just don't support it at all, in particular older CPUs or those on smartphones. There is [evidence](http://lemire.me/blog/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/) that there is little or no performance penalty for at least *some* use cases on at least *some* modern CPUs (but you should also read the article's comments, as they contain a lot of counterexamples).